# Azure Log Analytics configured for Application Insights showing performing assessment for very long

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-oms

I am trying to load the logs from Application Insights to OMS in Microsoft Azure. The issue is arising when I am trying to get this data using Application Insights connector and the OMS portal shows me **Performing Assessment** continuously. Is it normal it already 1 day since this is shown? And Its a demo application which have very less logs.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause maybe due to `the Application Insights connector management solution is no longer required and will be deprecated. Starting July, you will not be able to link new Application Insights resources to Log Analytics workspaces.`

Please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-app-insights-connector).

And OMS is moving to Azure, you can use the new portal as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-oms-portal-transition).